# Is there a way to delete the brances automatically not a cross line when a branch is deleted from github Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to find out a way to delete the removed or merged branches from github from Jenkins normally when there is a Jenkinsfile it automatically detects and shows on jenkins but when that particular brnach is removed from github we get a **CROSS** line on jenkins and have to delete that pipeline manually.

Is there a way when a banch in removed from github it automatically removes from jenkins and not show that branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a research I found a way if you use **BRANCH SOURCE** as GitHub and set **Orpahned Item Stratergy** to 0 or unselect it then the PR's that are merged or branches that are removed from GitHub will be automatically removed from Jenkins.
PS- Only works with **BRANCH SOURCE** as GitHub not **Git**